# Operation that returns a unique result for each unordered set of numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What operation $f$ can I apply to any two numbers $a$ & $b$, such that $$f(a,b) = f(b,a)$$
where $f(a,b)$ is unique for any combination of a & b in the set of whole numbers?

P.S. I'm really not sure what tag to use here, I'd appreciate someone adding the correct one.

#### A word on *why*:

I have a database table with two columns $a$ and $b$.
I'd like to ensure that there are no duplicate rows in my table.
However, I don't care about the order of $a$ and $b$.

```
a | b
--+--
1 | 2
2 | 1
```

Is effectively a duplicate.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean? It is not clear what you mean by "where $f(a,b)$ is unique for any combination of $a$ & $b$ in the set of whole numbers".

Comment: What kind of question is this? $f$ can be addition or multiplication, or any other symmetric binary operation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time expressing the second part of the requirement. 
I'd like for any given set of inputs to yield a unique result. 
The addition function fails this criteria because there are many numbers that can be summed together to produce the same result. Yes, $5+3$ = $3+5$ but $5+3$ = $7+1$.

Comment: I want $f(a,b)$ to only be equal to $f(b,a)$.

Comment: I think that there might be a better (both in terms of efficiency as well as understandability) solution to this if you are writing a program. You might want to ask about that on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution can use the property that the set of rational numbers is countable. You can use a slightly modified [pairing function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) to construct a function which satisfies the restrictions.

Comment: The Cantor pairing function seems to have put me on the right track towards this stack overflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919612/mapping-two-integers-to-one-in-a-unique-and-deterministic-way

Comment: Maybe the simplest solution , if I understand well your database problem ,is to generate increasing combinations of pairs of two numbers...what do you think about it? I don't know if it's possible to do it in your framework though

Comment: @Tortar Hello, do you think there is a simpler solution than the one I posted? Defining $f$ by parts seems natural...

Comment: @Tortar, unfortunately $a, b$ are user selectable and therefore I can't really constrain them in any way.

Comment: @Bcpicao I think that assuming $a \leq b$ is kind of cheating your way around the symmetry condition :P If you consider this to be fine, your solution is the simplest one I know in terms of proving the desired properties; I do not know whether the same thing can be said about the computational complexity of your function. Anyways, I gave a solution which does not assume $a \leq b$ which is kind of similar to yours.

Comment: Actually, if you assume $a \leq b$ something like $b^2 +a$ should work.

Comment: @Mathieu pasquet , I didn't expect it's one of the best function to use for you problem , I wasn't aware of its usefulness in CS , very cool ahah

Comment: @Watercrystal If you will, but I really don’t think so. Using max and min functions (or even absolute values) are all trivial operations that are recurrent when defining functions. Indeed, I think $b^2+a$ is even better, as it requires fewer operations to execute. My example took the more canonical route, which is normally used to find bijections.

Answer (score 2):

One could use
$$ f(a, b) = 2^{2a + 1} + 2^{2b + 1}. $$
It is easy to see that $f$ satisfies $f(a, b) = f(b, a)$.
Note that $2^{2x + 1} > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb Z$ and also (letting $x = \max \{a, b\}$) we have 
$$2^{2x + 1} < f(a, b) \leq 2 \cdot 2^{2x + 1}.$$

To prove that $f$ has your uniqueness condition, we consider cases depending on two pairs $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ (where without loss of generality the first number in the pair is the larger one) of whole numbers:

1. $a = c, b \neq d$ or $a \neq c, b = d$: Should be clear from the definition of $f$.
2. $a \neq c, b \neq d$. Then by symmetry (one could exchange the pairs) we may assume $a < c$ and hence 
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   f(a, b)
   &= 2^{2a + 1} + 2^{2b + 1} \\
   &\leq 2 \cdot 2^{2a + 1} \\
   &< 2^{2(a + 1) + 1} \\
   &\leq 2^{2c + 1} \\
   &\leq f(c, d).
   \end{align*}
   $$
   In particular, this means $f(a, b) \neq f(c, d)$.

It follows that $f$ is a function satisfying your conditions :)

Answer (score 0):

What you’re after is a function $f:\mathbb{N}^2\to \mathbb{N}$ that is injective in the half planes under and over $y=x$ and satisfies $f(a,b)=f(b,a)$. Since $\mathbb{N}^n$ is equipotent to $\mathbb{N}$ such a function exists and one takes usually defines $f$ as (supposing $a\leq b$):

$$f(a,b)=2^a3^b$$ and

$$f(b,a)=f(a,b)$$

Comment: I answer you here ! I think that your solution is simpler than mine but in terms of efficiency is bad because it is based on powers.

Comment: @Tortar Indeed, $f(a,b)=a+b^2$ is much better.